# Radare2 only printing out the last byte at RSP when using pxq @ rsp

Tags: debugging, binary-analysis, radare2

According to documentation,

> `px[?][owq] [len]`          hexdump of N bytes (o=octal, w=32bit, q=64bit)

and

> `pr[?][glx] [len]`           print N raw bytes (in lines or hexblocks,
> 'g'unzip)

These two commands are how you see the bytes at a certain address in radare2.

Here is the top of my stack in radare2:

[image: top of stack]

When I want to print out the 8 bytes RSP is pointing to by typing `pxq @ rsp`, I only get the last two bytes. See here:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due the blocksize, try running `b` to display the current blocksize and change it to something bigger than 1 byte like this: `b 1K`. Also I would suggest you to use @r:SP instead of `rsp` for portability and sync between regstate and flags reasons.

Hope that works